# Непонятная сущность ! this (определение контекста вызова)

Tags: javascript, объекты, this

Почему в данном примере, при вызове `ass.myBind(0)` или `ass.myBind(false)` возвращается `undefined`?
Ведь это значения , которые интерпретируются как `false` и попадая в конструкцию `fn.call(!this?this:obj)` по идее должно получиться (true?**this**:obj) - *жирным выделено то, что должно вернуться результатом*,  Т.Е. если возвращается `this` будет выполнена `привязка по умолчанию` т.е. объект `window`(учитывая то, в каком месте функция вызывается). И к тому-же, если вызывать `ass.myBind(unefined)` и `ass.myBind(null)` то привзяка по умолчанию работает (т.е привязка к глобальному объекту)!

```js
Function.prototype.myBind=function(obj){
  fn=this
    bound=function(){
        return fn.call(!this ? this : obj)
    }
    return bound
};

var a="Привязка к глобальному объекту по умолчанию",
    b={a:"Свойство 'а' из объекта b"},
    c={a:"Свойство 'а' из объекта с"},
    f //просто переменная для теста, т.к. у нее нет значения, значит она undefined
      //и соотвественно при передачи её аргументом ass.myBind(f) привязка идёт к
      //window

function ass(){
  document.write(this.a);
};

var fart = ass.myBind();

fart(); //привязка к глобальному объекту
```

Comment: Добавь use strict и результат будет другой.

Comment: @Grundy, и что ты там отметил как дубликат? У тебя про конкретный случай (мой) там одна строчка - "если в качестве контекста передан `null` или `undefined`, то `this` будет установлен на `window`" (разумеется речь идёт о привязке `this` с помощью bind)! А где случаи с `foo.myBind(0)` или `foo.myBind(false)`? Или ты невнимательно читал вопрос, которой "задублил"?

Comment: А ты внимательно прочитал?

Comment: @ Grundy, если ты там в своём ответе явно видишь ответ на мой вопрос, то я могу за тебя только порадоваться, твои ответы я читал, ничего про 0 и false там не было

Comment: Добавил еще один дубликат.

Comment: В общем ты путаешь `this` который внутри функции `bound` и `this` у которого ты берешь `a`.

Comment: @Grundy нужно открывать специальный раздел форума, связанный с this bind call apply ;)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, там все просто на самом деле: у каждой `function` **свой** `this`, который зависит от того как создали функции и как ее вызвали.

Comment: @Grundy, ну как же я путаю? Если я передаю в `ass.myBind();` в виде контекста объект `b` и, то он и выводит то, что содержится в объекте `b`! То-есть получается , что в проверке `fn.call(!this ? this : obj)` "ловится" этот самый объект контекста переданный мною!

Comment: @Grundy просто то просто, но вопросов связанных Вы уже поназакрывали вагон и маленькую тележку только за те 4 месяца которые я тут активно присутствую на ru.stackoverflow :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ вопросы с контекстом оч популярные, ну и `this` с первого раза сложно понять, так что это никогда не кончится)

Comment: @ThisMan да вот я выше и пошутил про this.ru.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Muranx, ты не прав. просто добавь `console.log` во все места где у тебя есть `this` и посмотри где какое значение

Comment: @Grundy, когда ты пишешь подобные вещи, закидываешь людей ссылками на свои ответы, вставляешь "дубликаты в колёса", ты должен предполагать, что уровень знаний у всех разный, что кто-то сразу понимает, кто-то позже, кто-то вообще спустя года заблуждений узнаёт то, как это действительно работает на самом деле! Я не думаю, что было бы для тебя сложно написать фразу что при вызове `foo.myBind(0)` мы на самом деле передаём экземпляр класса `Number`, в котором выполняется поиск переменной `а`, которой там нет!

Comment: @Grundy, и если к примеру сделать так - `Number.prototype.a=1000` то и результат будет не `undefined` а 1000!

Comment: @Muranx, я и написал, что ты не тот `this` смотришь.

Comment: @Grundby, ой кончай уже. . . ты либо реально не врубаешься , либо такой тонкий троль, который просто испытывает терпение нормальных людей!